# Text wrap around all sides of an image

Tags: image, tinymce

I am quite new to working with Tiny. I'm trying to figure out if it is possible to wrap text around an image on all sides. IE if the image is moved, the text would re-flow around it. Is this possible and if so, can anybody offer suggestions on how to configure this?
Many thanks!
Patsky

I did some research by reading the Tiny docs and searching on this forum, but didn't find the solution.